# Authentication fails for get request using Asp.net Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, owin

I have a Api Controller which returns a image for get request. I want to authorize this request. So I added the Authorize attribute to action. I am using Asp.net Identity framework for authorization. When I run my application  I logged in to application using username/password sending to /Token via ajax. Then I get the access_token and store it. Problem is when I reference an Image tag with src attrib (which that src points to the above said api controller), I don't have a way to send access token with that. How will i implement this?

```
    public partial class Startup
{
    static Startup()
    {
        PublicClientId = "self"; 
        UserManagerFactory = () => new UserManager<User>(new UserStore<User>(new ImagePerfektDbContext())); 
        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId, UserManagerFactory),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };
    }

    public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }

    public static Func<UserManager<User>> UserManagerFactory { get; set; }

    public static string PublicClientId { get; private set; } 
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    { 
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
        });
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie); 
        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
```

Comment: Are we talking about an MVC application or a Web forms application?  I'm confused

Comment: It's a MVC 5 application

Answer (score 1):

I see what you mean. It's never a good idea to append the access token in the src attribute URL as a route parameter either.

What I would do...assuming you are storing the access token in the authentication ticket, I would mark the action method with "Anonymous" action filter and remove the "Authorize" action filter.  Then, inside the action method code, I would attempt to retrieve the access token from authentication ticket (or wherever you are storing it), validate it and finally return the image, or not, based on the success of the validation.

I hope it makes sense

Leo

Comment: noo.. I'm not planning to send access token in url. I want to send it via cookies(since cannot set a header). But as i can see, [Authorize] attrib only recognize headers only. Problem is i want authorize attrib to authorze via cookies

Comment: Well, the solution I mentioned should work. I still don't know why you have to use the Authorize filter which obviously doesn't work for this scenario. Why not extend it? Why not override the Authorize filter to validate the access token sent in the Authentication ticket? It's not a big job and should get it working in less than an hour

Comment: I was thinking whether there is a built in way to do this, since its obvious scenario.

Comment: Frankly speaking, I've never run into this issue and I believe the Authorize filter is the only built-in filter of its kind along with the Anonymous one. Based on that I would recommend you to either implement my answer's solution or extend the Authorize filter. If you choose the latter make sure the implementation is thread-safe to avoid unexpected behavior